# render html using jstl with html tags intact

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl, spring-el

I am trying to render this string:

```
"<p>bold: <i>test</i> food <b>journal</b> entry</p>"
```

using jstl like these:

```
1) <c:out value="${topic.text}" escapeXml="true"/>
2) <c:out value="${topic.text}" escapeXml="false"/> 
3) ${topic.text}
```

None of these work as expected. I want the text to be shown as html. However the results are (as printed on the browser):

```
1) <p>bold: <i>test</i> food <b>journal</b> entry</p>

2) bold: test food journal entry

3) bold: test food journal entry
```

How can I get:
     test *food* **journal** entry

Comment: never mind, I found the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The last one you have `${topic.text}` will output the raw string exactly as it is with no escaping, if that one isn't working the string is probably not what you think it is. Is there a chance that something is modifying the string such as the `getText` getter?

Comment: yes, you are right. Actually, I removed <p> tags in my input string and now it is fine. may be <p> has some styling defined in css which is causing this.

Answer (score -2):

Use this.

```
 <c:set var="str" value="<p>bold: <i>test</i> food <b>journal</b> entry</p>" />
    <c:set var="str1">${str}</c:set>
    ${str1}
```